# Is the name of structure represent its address?

Tags: c, data-structures, structure

Is the name of structure represent its address, is it true?? plzz explain

```
struct s{
int a;
char b;
};
struct s s1;
struct s *ptr;
```

is writing 's1' represent the address of s1, means 's1' or '&s1' are same thing???

```
ptr=&s1;
ptr=s1; 
// which is correct??
```

Comment: *Is the name of structure represent its address?* Not really.  You may be thinking of arrays.  When you mention the name of an array in an expression, the value you get is a pointer to the array's first element.  But that's not true for structures, or any other kind of data.  (If you're a compiler writer, *any* identifier is basically a synonym for its address, but that's not normally the way we think about it when merely using an HLL like C.)

Comment: Always turn on compiler warnings and you will know.

Answer (score 0):

s1 and ptr are two different types s and pointer to s respectively.
so `ptr=s1;` won't compile. You are mixing here with the behavior of array:

```
int a[5];
int* ptr = a;
```

you can see the compiler error [live](https://godbolt.org/z/v1jEx5f46)